# Mockito + Dexmaker test crashes when run on Android < 4.4

Tags: android, mockito, dalvik, dexmaker

I have some android-tests that crash hard when run on android versions under 4.4 / Kitkat.

These are the libraries I have in my build.gradle

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1'
```

The tests run just as expected on android version 4.4, although I needed to add some hints to tell Dexmaker where to put its cache:

```
System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getInstrumentation().getContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
```

Here is the logcat output from the device:

```
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 479K, 19% free 2532K/3124K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 427K, 18% free 2595K/3136K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 311K, 16% free 2686K/3188K, paused 3ms+0ms, total 4ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 127K, 11% free 2852K/3188K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 123K, 7% free 3239K/3476K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 53K, 6% free 3276K/3476K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 10ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'Generated-1815896169.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
D/dalvikvm( 1728): DexOpt: load 1ms, verify+opt 0ms, 82180 bytes
D/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: --- END 'Generated-1815896169.jar' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm( 1712): DEX prep '/data/data/my.app.identifier/cache/Generated-1815896169.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 15ms
I/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: illegal method access (call Ljava/lang/Object;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object; from LBackendAddressServiceImpl_Proxy;)
I/dalvikvm( 1712): Could not find method my.app.identifier.backend.BackendAddressServiceImpl.internalClone, referenced from method BackendAddressServiceImpl_Proxy.internalClone
W/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 50: Lmy/app/identifier/backend/BackendAddressServiceImpl;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
D/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0019
I/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: illegal method access (call Ljava/lang/Object;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object; from LBackendAddressServiceImpl_Proxy;)
I/dalvikvm( 1712): Could not find method my.app.identifier.backend.BackendAddressServiceImpl.internalClone, referenced from method BackendAddressServiceImpl_Proxy.super$internalClone$java_lang_Object
W/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: unable to resoldlve virtual method 50: Lmy/app/identifier/backend/BackendAddressServiceImpl;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
D/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 652K, 20% free 3138K/3904K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'Generated1066861752.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 44K, 21% free 3103K/3904K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1729): DexOpt: load 0ms, verify+opt 0ms, 81004 bytes
D/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: --- END 'Generated1066861752.jar' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm( 1712): DEX prep '/data/data/my.app.identifier/cache/Generated1066861752.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 13ms
I/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: illegal method access (call Ljava/lang/Object;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object; from LAppConfigServiceImpl_Proxy;)
I/dalvikvm( 1712): Could not find method my.app.identifier.config.AppConfigServiceImpl.internalClone, referenced from method AppConfigServiceImpl_Proxy.internalClone
W/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17: Lmy/app/identifier/config/AppConfigServiceImpl;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
D/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0019
I/dalvikvm( 1712): DexOpt: illegal method access (call Ljava/lang/Object;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object; from LAppConfigServiceImpl_Proxy;)
I/dalvikvm( 1712): Could not find method my.app.identifier.config.AppConfigServiceImpl.internalClone, referenced from method AppConfigServiceImpl_Proxy.super$internalClone$java_lang_Object
W/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17: Lmy/app/identifier/config/AppConfigServiceImpl;.internalClone (Ljava/lang/Cloneable;)Ljava/lang/Object;
D/dalvikvm( 1712): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 22% free 3078K/3904K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 7ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 492K, 21% free 3098K/3904K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 20% free 3142K/3904K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 19% free 3174K/3904K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 4ms
F/libc    ( 1712): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1725 (ationTestRunner)
I/DEBUG   (  109): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  109): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.2.2/JDQ39E/eng.buildbot.20140523.235904:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  109): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  109): pid: 1712, tid: 1725, name: ationTestRunner  >>> my.app.identifier 
I/DEBUG   (  109): 
I/DEBUG   (  109): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bba0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bba4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bba8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbac  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbb0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbb4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbb8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbbc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbc0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbc4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbc8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbcc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbd0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbd4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbd8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbdc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):     #00  98c5bbe0  a652fb68  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbe4  a6487fe8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbe8  a647f1c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbec  b66af3d1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmRemoveFromReferenceTable(ReferenceTable*, Object**, Object*)+33)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbf0  b6752ca0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbf4  b6751ff4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbf8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bbfc  b66b3fd4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmThreadSelf()+36)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc00  00000007  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc04  a652fc08  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc08  a647f198  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc0c  b6751ff4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc10  b7d30a28  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc14  a647f180  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc18  98c5bcb8  [stack:1725]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bc1c  b66ba5b7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmReleaseTrackedAlloc+71)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  109):     #01  98c5bcc0  b7d30a28  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcc4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcc8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bccc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcd0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcd4  b6751ff4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcd8  b7d30a28  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcdc  b665bd72  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+178)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bce0  b7d30a28  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bce4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bce8  b7596339  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+9)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcec  b761eff4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcf0  b7cf4e98  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcf4  00000018  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcf8  b7cf4e68  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          98c5bcfc  b7596509  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_unlock+25)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  109):     #02  b7d30a30  9f27f620  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a34  9eee8000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a38  a647f180  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a3c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a40  98c5bc70  [stack:1725]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a44  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a48  98c5bd1c  [stack:1725]
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a4c  0000000a  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a50  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a54  b665611c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a58  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a5c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a60  9edb6670  /system/framework/ext.jar
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a64  98c5c300  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a68  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  109):          b7d30a6c  00000000  
D/AndroidRuntime( 1704): Shutting down VM
I/ActivityManager(  464): Process my.app.identifier (pid 1712) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  464): Crash of app my.app.identifier running instrumentation ComponentInfo{my.app.identifier.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
D/dalvikvm( 1704): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 19% free 462K/568K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 2ms
D/jdwp    ( 1704): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
D/dalvikvm( 1704): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/ActivityManager(  464): Force stopping package my.app.identifier appid=10048 user=0
D/Zygote  (  198): Process 1712 terminated by signal (11)
W/ThrottleService(  464): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

Are there any hints on running Mockito / Dexmaker on "older" android-versions?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this, I am facing the same kind of issue, in my case device is also getting reboot.

Comment: No success thus far! I think this issue might be related https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100 % if that did it (or something else we changed in the meantime) but with Dexmaker 1.2 this seems to be fixed.